# need toview 2 computers on one monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect two computers to one monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/455736/how-to-connect-two-computers-to-one-monitor)

I am using window easy transfer to move files from a Vista computer to a new windows7 computer and only have one monitor. Is there a way to view both pcs on the on the one monitor?

Answer (score 0):

You can remote desktop (or VNC or $random other app) into the other computer. That way you have the desktop from the other computer in  a windows on the primary computer.